# Revise google sheet script to copy values and not formulas

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to modify the script below so only the VALUES are copied to another sheet rather than the formulas. Thanks!

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named ClientList
  // target sheet of move to named CLOSED
  // test column with C is col 7 or G
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "ClientList" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getDisplayValue() == "C1" || r.getDisplayValue() == "C2" || r.getDisplayValue() == "C3") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CLOSED");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You want to copy only values without including the formulas.

  - Each cell including the formulas is copied as the calculated result.

If my understanding is correct, how about modifying as follows?

#### From:

```
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
```

#### To:

```
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target, {contentsOnly: true});
```

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-options)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: @Mark I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.