# Pasting sheet data without formatting (Google sheets Javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to copy only values from one sheet to another in Google sheets without the formatting, I'm thinking it's a "PasteSpecial" but cannot for the life of me work out how to do this.

My code looks like this, any pointers? (I'm quite new to this!)

EDIT: Solved with [Revise google sheet script to copy values and not formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549162/revise-google-sheet-script-to-copy-values-and-not-formulas)

```
function copyInfo() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("SheetA");
var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SheetB");

// get source range
var source = copySheet.getRange("D2:K");

// get destination range
var destination = pasteSheet.getRange("A4:M");

// copy values to destination range
source.copyTo(destination);
```

}

Comment: In your script, please modify `source.copyTo(destination);` to `source.copyTo(destination, { contentsOnly: true });`, and test it again. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?#copytodestination,-options)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your question, I flagged it as a duplicate question.